# What are the differences between Dynamic Time Warping and Needleman-Wunsch algorithm?

Tags: time-series, alignment, bioinformatics, data-mining

I am looking for the differences between [Dynamic Time Warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) and [Needleman-Wunsch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman-Wunsch_algorithm).

Basically, they both find an alignment score. I need to calculate alignment (similarity) score between short sequence of strings (<20 characters) and there are a couple of thousands of them.

I wasn't able to figure out the differences between the two algorithms and decide which one to choose for my work. Can anyone please clear me the differences?

Comment: Why not use a simple edit distance, such as the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: Edit distance won't work for me as I need to align the string sequence first

Comment: I wonder if bioconducter would be a better fit for this question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both of these algorithms use dynamic programming to determine an alignment of sequential data.  The major difference here is how the score for `i,j` is determined.

In Dynamic Time Warping, a cost (determined by a function of `i, j`) is added to the minimum value of the set `(i-1, j)`, `(i-1, j-1)`, `(j, i-1)`.

In NW, the maximum of the set `(i-1, j) + weight`, `(i-1, j-1) + S(Ai, Bi)`, `(j, i-1) + weight` is taken, such that `S(A, B)` is determined by a look up in the similarity matrix.

If you would like to make an alignment through enumerable space and can create a similarity matrix, (such as a protein sequence or words), use NW, however, if you are aligning data where you can't make a similarity matrix (like a time series), and need to use a function, go with DTW.

Alignments can be a tricky thing, and you may have to tweak parameters to get things right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still I have confusions.Do you mean that I cant use DTW for string alignment? Will DTW and NW will produce a same alignment for a given string sequence?

Comment: You could use DTW for sting alignment, as long as you can calculate cost as a function of A, B.  Whether or not they produce the same alignment for a given sequence depends on 1) the content of the sequence 2) the gap penalty & similarity matrix for NW 3) the cost function for DWT.

Comment: Yeah..i can compute cost as a function of A,B. How would the content of the sequence would effect the alignment given that I run both algorithms under identical conditions.

Comment: NW would disfavor gaps, becuase DTW doesn't assign a gap penalty, but rather weighs each event, insertion, deletion, gap equally.  It may be that sequence N will be aligned differently under these two algorithms as a function of its sequence, but I'm not able to prove that. Two small strings, of equal length and composition would be aligned the same, but as difference in length and composition come into play, its hard to imagine that the two algos would align them the same.  They way to find out is to do a side by side comparison of the alignment, and look for features that indicate a differnc

Comment: I would venture to say they are almost identical algorithmically. The highest "weights" in NW seem to correspond to the lowest previous scores in neighboring cells in DTW. It seems to me that DTW is a continuous and inverse version of the discretely weighted NW. Would you agree, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

The fundamental difference between Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) and the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm (NW) is in the way the sequence elements are accounted for in the alignment.

A basic assumption of DTW is that one sequence is a "time-warped" version of the other, in the sense that the target sequence is either stretched (one-to-many alignment), condensed (many-to-one alignment), or non-warped (one-to-one alignment) with respect to the source sequence.

Thus, DTW is not compatible with the notion of *gaps*, where one or more elements in one sequence are not matched by any elements in the other sequence (one-to-none or none-to-one alignment). By contrast, NW accounts for gaps explicitly with a penalty that is not a function of the elements to be inserted/deleted.

If you need to align character sequences, DTW is only appropriate in the unlikely case that the sequences are strictly "time warped" versions of each other, such as "wow" and "wwooowww". As soon as one sequence contains elements that cannot be construed as the result of stretching the other sequence, such as the exclamation marks in "wow" vs "wwooowww!!!", DTW is not appropriate, since it forces you to define the cost of inserting a "!" in terms of the distance with respect to a "w" or an "o".

Answer (score 1):

How about using Jarowinkler for similarity measure and Levenshtein for measuring the distance (minimum number of edition)